# Evaporation rate of Miscible Liquids

Tags: data-analysis, data

I am currently on a small individual research project researching the evaporation rate of miscible liquids and have some questions about the data that I have received and how to interpret it. The following graph shows the data gathered over 5 repeats for each concentration of a mixture of ethanol and water by % volume for various temperatures. The errors are standard errors represented by the std deviation of each repeat. The best fit for this data I believe is exponential which produces decent r^2 value. The method of acquiring data was through tensiometry using a youngs-laplace fit which does not account for asymmetry hence why some of the data points are not very precise.[image]

I then plotted this on a ln axis to recieve the following -
[image: The top eq box refers to the top line and so on...]

I would like to know where to start the analysis of this data as the two gradients of the 45 and 60 degree lines are comparable whereas the bottom line seems to follow an exp relationship even though it has already been logged!

Many thanks
Harry

Comment: The first step to analysis should be looking for a model that justifies the exponential fit. Otherwise, the extracted fitting parameters have little underlying meaning.